# What's going wrong with my golang stldib sort?

Tags: sorting, go

I am trying to sort a (Golang) slice of structs by one of their fields.

I have looked at a lot of examples and go-playgrounds and the documentation, and I feel like I get it, but I still can't get my code to work quite right.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Method struct {
    MethodNumber int       `json:"methodNumber"`
    MethodRank   int       `json:"rank"`
    MethodRMSE   float64   `json:"error"`
    Forecast     []float64 `json:"forecast"`
}

// extra stuff for sorting.
type ByError []Method

func (s ByError) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}
func (s ByError) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}
func (s ByError) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s[i].MethodRMSE < s[i].MethodRMSE
}

func main() {

    xs := make([]Method, 0)
    fmt.Println(len(xs))
    xs = append(xs, Method{MethodNumber: 1, MethodRMSE: 10})
    xs = append(xs, Method{MethodNumber: 2, MethodRMSE: 8})
    xs = append(xs, Method{MethodNumber: 3, MethodRMSE: 6})
    xs = append(xs, Method{MethodNumber: 4, MethodRMSE: 4})

    fmt.Printf("%+v \n", xs)
    sort.Sort(ByError(xs))
    fmt.Printf("%+v \n", xs)
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(ByError(xs)))
    fmt.Printf("%+v \n", xs)


}
```

My Non-Working Code : https://play.golang.org/p/h8SHVjTQSPM

A Working Near-Duplicate : https://play.golang.org/p/vActL0VwK3L (from another SO user)

Mine should be sorting by RMSE, but it doesn't change the order at all. Right now, the result of  my go playground should be having it sort by RMSE ascending, then sort in reverse.

Comment: In your `Less` function you're using element `i` on both sides of the comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

typo here

```
func (s ByError) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s[i].MethodRMSE < s[i].MethodRMSE
}
```

should be

```
func (s ByError) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s[i].MethodRMSE < s[j].MethodRMSE
}
```

Because it's a little hard to see, the first (wrong) version compares the item to itself (both indexes are `i`). The second properly uses both `i` and `j`.